# Can XDebug track separately the time spent for profiler calls?

Tags: php, performance, profiler, xdebug

I am using XDebug as a profiler for a PHP application. I have run into a situation where XDebug changes severely the results in such a degree that they are useless.

Here a simplified example to demonstrate the problem:

```
function foo(){ $x = 1; }
function bar(){ foo(); }
```

Test A:

```
$t0 = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++) foo();
echo microtime(true) - $t0;
```

Test B:

```
$t0 = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++) bar();
echo microtime(true) - $t0;
```

So, these are the results I am getting (in seconds):

```
          profiler  | profiler  > profiler
          disabled  | enabled   > results
          --------------------------------------------------------------------
          output    | output    > total time   time in foo()   time in bar()
Test A    0.159     | 12.199    > 12.245       0.110           - (not called)
Test B    0.233     | 25.399    > 25.578       0.104           11.068
```

The increased execution time is expected because of the extra calls to the profiler. The slight variation between the microtime-based output and the profiler results is also expected. I have repeated the tests several times, and the results are always similar.

From the results taken from Test B with the profiler disabled, we can say that the script spends about 0.159 seconds in foo() and 0.074 seconds in bar(). It is evident that time spent in bar() is less than the time spent in foo().

However, when I analyze the results of the profiler (with qcachegrind), the time *shown* as spent in bar() (= 11.068 seconds) is ridiculously higher than the time in foo() (=0.104 seconds). There is a possible explanation for this: each time a function call is made, the profiler runs some extra code to keep track of the time spent in the call. I believed that it excluded this extra time from the results, but apparently it does not.

**[EDIT]**
As a result, the profiler says that bar() takes more time than foo() in this program, which is not the case as we have measured with the profiler disabled. It's not even close! The relative results (the percentage of time taken by each function) are totally wrong. This should not be expected, because, if this is the case, the profiler can not indicate which function takes most of the time. Although the absolute times are expected to have (big) differences, the relative times should not have.
**[/EDIT]**

This renders the results unusable. Any code that is more modular (with more function calls, wrappers, objects etc.) is severely penalized, although it is not *that* slower!

So the question is: Is there any way to tell XDebug to **ignore** or **track separately** the extra time spent for the profiler calls?

Comment: Off-topic, but I've heard about [XHProf](http://pecl.php.net/package/xhprof), which can be used in production because it is said not to affect performances.

Comment: @greg0ire, I have tested XHProf. It works better than XDebug and it does not have the problem I described. Still, it's strange that XDebug, the most wide-spread profiler for PHP, has such a serious problem and nobody complained.

Comment: I guess it still makes it possible to see where the problems are in most cases. Or perhaps there is a way to ignore the extra time spent in profiler calls...

Comment: Could you post the profile file? I'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunatelly, it is not possible. I am no longer using XDebug as a profiler and I suggest that nobody should use it.

Answer (score 2):

It is known that xdebug behaves like that and actually no news. Sorry, obviously this is news to you, and I don't want to say *everybody* needs to know that.

As an explanation: xdebug does the *whole* job, from beginning to end, dumping/metricating everyhing as announced. This *comes* with a price (how couldn't it?).

If you need to pick metrics in an isolated context within your script, you should not run xdebug. Or as your question shows: You're trying to profile xdebug with xdebug switched on (with PHP code!). That won't really work, you can't profile a PHP compiled C extension with PHP user-code, or at least I won't trust that much. Imagine the lib is changing the behaviour of the interpreter, that same interpreter your profiling code is running on.

If you really need to profile a specific part of your code isolated, xdebug is just not the tool of choice. Look for xhprof or maybe in a real life environment [Pinba](http://hakre.wordpress.com/2011/02/12/pinba-realtime-monitoring-and-statistics-server-for-php/).

Comment: I am sorry, but my intention is not to profile XDebug itself. I want to profile two versions of my code, as a whole. The first version has many function calls while the other does not. XDebug severely penalises the first version and it is therefore useless. Yes this is news to me and I disagree that I should have expected from a profiler to behave that way. -- I agree however to use xhprof, I have been playing with it for the last days and the results are very good.

Comment: @linepogl: I did wanted to say that your intention *is* to profile XDebug. I just wanted say that you did and that this most likely does not work with PHP usercode. That's a slight difference I wanted to make clear in which problems you can run with such way of "verifying". Just that that :) It's not useless, it's just that xdebug is most likely the wrong tool for the job (profile isolated parts).

Comment: @hakre: please use a direct link to http://pinba.org/ instead of using your own blog

Answer (score 2):

you are not supposed to expect the profilers results to be the same as normal opperation, it is inposseble(or you have to slow down opperation whith is not desireble)

but still the times in de profiler are verry usefull for example you can see that altrug the scripexcution taks longer the results are (some wat) cosistent with scale

using profilers is usefull to pointout problem spots, but ther results cannot be the same as reallife is to mutch optimized(at least with xdbug)

Comment: As I have said in the question, I have no problem with the extra time taken. And as you say, the role of the profilers is to spot the points where a program spends the majority of the time. It should be expected that the _relative_ time spent in a function is not affected much by the profiler. In this case however, the profiler says that the program spends most of its time in an _empty_ function...

Comment: yes and for your code this is 0.233 - 0.159 = 0.074 sec in `bar()` whitch is 31 % of the time spend,

Comment: Of course profiling times couldn't be the same as running the code in production, but shoud at least be proportionate, which they aren't, rendering xdebug pretty useless for profiling, at least in my case.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely give `xhprof` a try. Seems less prone to errors. Not to knock `Xdebug`.